# Future updates to college scorecard?

Tags: usa, collegescorecard

Does anyone have any concrete knowledge of whether or not there are plans to continue to update the Scorecard each year? Specifically updates that include data for additonal years, not really the updates that fix coding errors.

My guess is that the answer to this depends heavily on our new Secretary of Education and funding levels, but if someone knows more about this I would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the future of the Scorecard is subject to changes initiated by the incoming administration.  However, the Department's current plans are to provide a major update (e.g. additional data) to the Scorecard annually.  Minor updates are anticipated to occur quarterly.